# Virtual Display Manager - Maximized Window Covered by Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, display, widescreen

I just got a large widescreen monitor and installed Virtual Display Manager to split my monitor in two. The problem is that when I maximize a window, the bottom of it is covered by the taskbar. Is there a fix for this? Alternatively: The functionality I want is to be able to maximize a window and have it take up only half of my screen. Is there a cheaper way of doing this than Virtual Display Manager in Windows 7 Professional?

Answer (score 0):

I'm bad at describing to Google exactly what I was trying to achieve. To answer my own question, I found WinSplit Revolution and Gridmove. Neither of them seemed to work with Firefox - they wouldn't get the window to stretch all vertically to the bottom. Windows+left/right does just what I need!